# Updating a random value in a Shiny UI input parameter every time the output is updated

Tags: r, shiny

This is a totally gratuitous use case, though I think I will learn something valuable from the answer :)

I want to show a random gif (randomly drawn from a list of pre-selected urls) while a shiny app loads the output.

I am using the `shinycssloaders` package to put in a spinner while the output loads, and feeding it an image from that list of urls. Below, the out-of-the-box histogram sample app with the spinner and some gif urls.

The gif url only appears to be sampled each time the app is loaded. I want it to re-select every time the output activities run (sorry if I'm butchering the technical terms here). My real app uses an `actionButton` with `eventReactive` so that the output only re-loads when the button is clicked.

Here's sample code that can be run. It sleeps for 3 seconds before loading the histogram after each input change in order to show the gif.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

gifs <- c(
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/QPQ3xlJhqR1BXl89RG/giphy.gif", 
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/26n6xBpxNXExDfuKc/giphy.gif", 
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/lP4jmO461gq9uLzzYc/giphy.gif"   
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            withSpinner(
                plotOutput("distPlot"), image = sample(gifs, 1)
            )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        Sys.sleep(3)
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Session Info:**

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinycssloaders_1.0.0 RODBC_1.3-18          shinythemes_1.2.0     DT_0.19               forcats_0.5.1        
 [6] stringr_1.4.0         dplyr_1.0.7           purrr_0.3.4           readr_2.0.1           tidyr_1.1.4          
[11] tibble_3.1.4          ggplot2_3.3.5         tidyverse_1.3.1       shiny_1.6.0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        lubridate_1.7.10  here_1.0.1        assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2   digest_0.6.27    
 [7] utf8_1.2.2        mime_0.11         R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.2.1   reprex_2.0.1     
[13] httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.6.2      rlang_0.4.11      readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13   jquerylib_0.1.4  
[19] htmlwidgets_1.5.4 bit_4.0.4         munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.9       compiler_4.1.1    httpuv_1.6.3     
[25] modelr_0.1.8      janitor_2.1.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.2   sourcetools_0.1.7 tidyselect_1.1.1 
[31] fansi_0.5.0       crayon_1.4.1      tzdb_0.1.2        dbplyr_2.1.1      withr_2.4.2       later_1.3.0      
[37] grid_4.1.1        jsonlite_1.7.2    xtable_1.8-4      gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.0   DBI_1.1.1        
[43] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      cachem_1.0.6      cli_3.0.1         stringi_1.7.4     vroom_1.5.4      
[49] fs_1.5.0          promises_1.2.0.1  snakecase_0.11.0  bslib_0.3.0       xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.2   
[55] keyring_1.2.0     generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8       tools_4.1.1       bit64_4.0.5       glue_1.4.2       
[61] crosstalk_1.1.1   hms_1.1.0         yaml_2.2.1        rsconnect_0.8.24  fastmap_1.1.0     colorspace_2.0-2 
[67] rvest_1.0.1       haven_2.4.3       sass_0.4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code that is inside the ui gets executed only once. We'll need to sample inside the server to keep changing the gif displayed. One way of doing this, is to use  `renderUI` to create a `plotOutput` with a different image each time.

Note that I added a reactive value named `signal`, that is to prevent the gif graying out that happens if we used `observeEvent(input$bins, {...})` to render the UI.

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

set.seed(111111111)

gifs <- c(
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/QPQ3xlJhqR1BXl89RG/giphy.gif",
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/26n6xBpxNXExDfuKc/giphy.gif",
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/lP4jmO461gq9uLzzYc/giphy.gif"
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30
            )
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("dynamic_gif")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    signal <- reactiveVal(rnorm(1))
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x <- faithful[, 2]
        Sys.sleep(1)
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        signal(rnorm(1)) # change the value for the observer to trigger
        
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "darkgray", border = "white")
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(signal(), {
        output$dynamic_gif <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                withSpinner(
                    plotOutput("distPlot"),
                    image = sample(gifs, 1)
                )
            )
        })
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I figured that having it in server was the solution, but I didn't know what kind of output to use. I didn't think about putting `withSpinner` itself in the server. Great, thanks!

Comment: I am having a problem actually getting this working... before I get into my own app, when I just copy your code into an app, the gif is not refreshing randomly. I'm getting the same one repeatedly. Is it possible we're on significantly different versions of R/Shiny? I'm adding mine in the question

Comment: I'm using shiny 1.7.1, yours is 1.6.0, but i don't know if that is the issue. I tested the app again with less sys.sleep and a different seed and it shows the different gifs.

Comment: Upgrading shiny did actually fix the test app. I'll try to apply this to my app later today

Comment: Got it working. I don't understand everything I'm doing, but that's okay. I'm going to work on building up my understanding of the reactive graph model of shiny as I continue to develop this thing.